# How to set up 3 kafka nodes (1 main and 2 replicas) on 3 different machines?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I want to have 3 kafka replicas on 3 different machines.

On the first machine my I start zookeeper with the following config file:

```
dataDir=/root/kafka/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
clientPortAddress=172.16.1.1
maxClientCnxns=0
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=172.16.1.2:2888:3888
server.3=172.16.1.3:2888:3888
```

where `dataDir` contains `myid` file with the value 1.

On the first machine I also start a kafka server with the following config file:

```
broker.id=1
port=9001
log.dirs=/root/logs/kafka-logs
zookeeper.connect=172.16.1.1:2181,172.16.1.2:2181,
                  172.16.1.3:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
advertised.host.name=172.16.1.1
```

On the second and third machine I start zookeeper and kafka servers with similar config files.

Then on the first machine I run a producer to produce 1000000 messages.

Now I want to consume these 1000000 messages with a consumer on each of the 3 machines.

The problem is:

- If I kill a kafka server on the first machine, no consumer consumes messages on the second or third machine. The other replicas do not seem to play a role in replicating the produced messages.

My question is: **how to properly set up kafka server and 2 replicas on different machines, such that consumers could read messages from kafka including the case of kafka server failures**?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the consumer offsets replication factor to be 3. Otherwise, consumers will hang when trying to lookup where they should read from when the topic is unavailable

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
```

Similarly, there's a setting for the transaction topic if you plan on using exactly-once features

Also, please do not store data under /tmp if it's important to you

Comment: Any ideas why the following problem still persists:

I successfully consume on machine 1 when all 3 kafka servers are running, but when I kill the server on machine 3, the consumer on machine 1 throws the following error:

`FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| ]: 172.16.1.3:9003/3: Disconnected (after 6553ms in state UP)`.

I have set the `offsets.topic.replication.factor` value to 3 in all 3 kafka server config files. If I restart the server on machine 3, the consumer on machine 1 resumes the consumption process.

Comment: Did you set it to 3 after the topic was already created? If you described the _consumer_offsets topic, how many in sync replicas are there? And your error seems like a general disconnection message

Comment: I started zookeeper, then kafka server on those machines, then created a topic: `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic read-topic 
--zookeeper 172.16.1.1:2181`, then started producing messages to this topic, then started consuming and the problem persists: if one kafka server is killed, the consumer stops consuming.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. There's another topic called `_consumer_offsets`. Please tell me how many replicas **it has** currently

Comment: `topic "__consumer_offsets" with 50 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 3, replicas: 3,1,2, isrs: 2,1,3`

Comment: Alright, so when you're producing messages, what acks setting did you give? When creating your other topic, you're only guaranteed one in-sync replica, by default.